# Split braces from single string in xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

A customer supplied XML contains a description with an open and close brace in XML string, I would like to split this string and display as a single string using XSLT 1.0.
XML STRING:

```
<tempDescs> Loans and deposits schedules_Loans and deposits schedule details_List of Today\'s Entries(Authorised)_List of entries (unauthorised)_Forward entries (unauthorised)_Forward Entries by transaction_ </tempDescs>
```

Code:

```
<xsl:variable name="descs">
                            <xsl:call-template name="remove-parentheses">
                                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$tempDescs"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:variable>


<xsl:template name="remove-parentheses">
        <xsl:param name="string" />
        <xsl:variable name="opb" select='"~Opb#"' />
        <xsl:variable name="clb" select='"~Clb#"' />
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- when open parenthesis is present remove it -->
            <xsl:when test="contains($string, $opb)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, $opb)" />
                <xsl:call-template name="remove-parentheses">
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $opb)" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- when close parenthesis is present remove it -->
            <xsl:when test="contains($string, $clb)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, $clb)" />
                <xsl:call-template name="remove-parentheses">
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $clb)" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- otherwise... -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!-- ... just give the value of the string -->
                <xsl:value-of select="$string" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

Im getting the output without splitting the close brace properly.

Loans and deposits schedules_Loans and deposits schedule details_List of Today's EntriesAuthorised)_List of entries unauthorised)*Forward entries unauthorised_Forward Entries by transaction*

Im expecting output without any brace

Loans and deposits schedules_Loans and deposits schedule details_List of Today's EntriesAuthorised_List of entries unauthorised_Forward entries unauthorised_Forward Entries by transaction_

Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you do simply:

```
translate(tempDescs, '()', '')
```

Comment: It is working for me: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aiyndV